# mutate dynamically columns based on other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression

I would like to mutate new columns with residuals by solving an easy equation of linear regression.

Let's say that I have the table below which contains more columns with the same structure. Each linear function has the same dependent variable.

| Dependent_VAR | X_Independent | X_Coefficient | X_Intercept | Y_Intependent | Y_Coefficient | Y_Intercept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 2000 | 3000 | 4500 | 500 | 750 | 600 |
| 3100 | 3000 | 3000 | 4500 | 670 | 750 | 600 |
| 52222 | 55500 | 3000 | 4500 | 700 | 750 | 600 |
| 400 | 456 | 3000 | 4500 | 800 | 750 | 600 |

I want to find the residual for each column name of the dataframe by creating new columns with the new name *name_Residual* like X_Residual = X_Independent-(X_Intercept+X_Coefficient*Dependent_VAR).
I would prefer a solution using dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to first reshape your data to tidy format using `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Afterwards computing the residuals is pretty straightforward:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat |> 
  pivot_longer(-Dependent_VAR, names_to = c("name", ".value"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  mutate(Residual = Independent - (Intercept + Dependent_VAR * Coefficient))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 6
#>   Dependent_VAR name  Independent Coefficient Intercept   Residual
#>           <int> <chr>       <int>       <int>     <int>      <int>
#> 1          1200 X            2000        3000      4500   -3602500
#> 2          1200 Y             500         750       600    -900100
#> 3          3100 X            3000        3000      4500   -9301500
#> 4          3100 Y             670         750       600   -2324930
#> 5         52222 X           55500        3000      4500 -156615000
#> 6         52222 Y             700         750       600  -39166400
#> 7           400 X             456        3000      4500   -1204044
#> 8           400 Y             800         750       600    -299800
```

And if necessary you could of course reshape back to wide afterwards:

```r
dat |> 
  pivot_longer(-Dependent_VAR, names_to = c("name", ".value"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  mutate(Residual = Independent - (Intercept + Dependent_VAR * Coefficient)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = !c(Dependent_VAR, name))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 9
#>   Dependent_VAR Indepe…¹ Indep…² Coeff…³ Coeff…⁴ Inter…⁵ Inter…⁶ Resid…⁷ Resid…⁸
#>           <int>    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#> 1          1200     2000     500    3000     750    4500     600 -3.60e6 -9.00e5
#> 2          3100     3000     670    3000     750    4500     600 -9.30e6 -2.32e6
#> 3         52222    55500     700    3000     750    4500     600 -1.57e8 -3.92e7
#> 4           400      456     800    3000     750    4500     600 -1.20e6 -3.00e5
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​Independent_X, ²​Independent_Y,
#> #   ³​Coefficient_X, ⁴​Coefficient_Y, ⁵​Intercept_X, ⁶​Intercept_Y, ⁷​Residual_X,
#> #   ⁸​Residual_Y
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Dependent_VAR = c(1200L, 3100L, 52222L, 400L),
  X_Independent = c(2000L, 3000L, 55500L, 456L),
  X_Coefficient = c(3000L, 3000L, 3000L, 3000L),
    X_Intercept = c(4500L, 4500L, 4500L, 4500L),
  Y_Independent = c(500L, 670L, 700L, 800L),
  Y_Coefficient = c(750L, 750L, 750L, 750L),
    Y_Intercept = c(600L, 600L, 600L, 600L)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach, it uses `!!sym(var)` to use the text stored in `var` as a variable name. There are several other ways to do the same thing, see the [Programming with dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

```r
prefix_list = c("X_","Y_")

for(prefix in prefix_list){
  this_independent = paste0(prefix,"Independent")
  this_coefficient = paste0(prefix,"Coefficient")
  this_intercept = paste0(prefix,"Intercept")
  this_interdependent = paste0(prefix,"Interpendent")
  this_residual = paste0(prefix,"Residual")

  df = df %>%
    mutate(!!sym(this_residual) := !!sym(this_independent) - !!sym(this_intercept) - !!sym(this_coefficient) * !!sym(this_interdepdendent))
}
```

Comment: Interested approach thank you for your answer!